# What's the best way to make this icon wiggle.. like jell-o

Tags: javascript, animation, yui

I'm trying to apply a little "wiggle" to an icon when you click on it using the YUI animation framework and Javascript.

Here's what I have right now:

```
var anim = new YAHOO.util.Anim(filter.Li, {top: { to: -5 }}, .10, YAHOO.util.Easing.bounceIn);
var anim2 = new YAHOO.util.Anim(filter.Li, {top: { to: 5 }}, .15, YAHOO.util.Easing.bounceBoth);
var anim3 = new YAHOO.util.Anim(filter.Li, {top: { to: 0 }}, .20, YAHOO.util.Easing.bounceOut);
anim.onComplete.subscribe(function() { anim2.animate(); });
anim2.onComplete.subscribe(function() { anim3.animate(); });

anim.animate();
```

First off, it's kinda lame that I have to chain together so many animations.  Is there a better way to do this?  Also, I'm not really all that pleased with the way it looks.  It's a bit too fluid, I'm looking to get more of a wobbly look.

Is there a better approach to do this sort of effect?  Thanks!

Comment: I have an answer elsewhere that I hope helps, with explanations on how to make your element [shake, rotate, squish, or skew](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74649470/2430549)!  Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it a little bit readable if you use recursion and i prefere the easyBoth animation method. Try this one:

```
var counter = 0,
    E = YAHOO.util.Easing,
    animationChain = [
        {attr: {top: {to: -5}}, duration: 0.08, method: E.easeBoth},
        {attr: {top: {to: 5}}, duration: 0.16, method: E.easeBoth},
        {attr: {top: {to: -5}}, duration: 0.16, method: E.easeBoth},
        {attr: {top: {to: 5}}, duration: 0.16, method: E.easeBoth},
        {attr: {top: {to: 0}}, duration: 0.08, method: E.easeBoth}
    ];

function animate() {
    var anim, current;

    if (animationChain[counter]) {
        current = animationChain[counter];
        counter += 1;
        anim = new YAHOO.util.Anim(filter.Li, current.attr, current.duration, current.method);
        anim.onComplete.subscribe(animate);
        anim.animate();
    }
}

animate();
```