# Javascript shake html element

Tags: javascript, html, css-animations

I'm trying to shake an html element for my game.

I found this code here:

```
shake = function (sprite, magnitude = 16, angular = false) {

  //A counter to count the number of shakes
  var counter = 1;

  //The total number of shakes (there will be 1 shake per frame)
  var numberOfShakes = 10;

  //Capture the sprite's position and angle so you can
  //restore them after the shaking has finished
  var startX = sprite.x,
      startY = sprite.y,
      startAngle = sprite.rotation;

  // Divide the magnitude into 10 units so that you can 
  // reduce the amount of shake by 10 percent each frame
  var magnitudeUnit = magnitude / numberOfShakes;

  //The `randomInt` helper function
  var randomInt = (min, max) => {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  };

  //Add the sprite to the `shakingSprites` array if it
  //isn't already there
  if(shakingSprites.indexOf(sprite) === -1) {
    //console.log("added")
    shakingSprites.push(sprite);

    //Add an `updateShake` method to the sprite.
    //The `updateShake` method will be called each frame
    //in the game loop. The shake effect type can be either
    //up and down (x/y shaking) or angular (rotational shaking).
    sprite.updateShake = () => {
      if(angular) {
        angularShake();
      } else {
        upAndDownShake();
      }
    };
  }

  //The `upAndDownShake` function
  function upAndDownShake() {

    //Shake the sprite while the `counter` is less than 
    //the `numberOfShakes`
    if (counter < numberOfShakes) {

      //Reset the sprite's position at the start of each shake
      sprite.x = startX;
      sprite.y = startY;

      //Reduce the magnitude
      magnitude -= magnitudeUnit;

      //Randomly change the sprite's position
      sprite.x += randomInt(-magnitude, magnitude);
      sprite.y += randomInt(-magnitude, magnitude);

      //Add 1 to the counter
      counter += 1;
    }

    //When the shaking is finished, restore the sprite to its original 
    //position and remove it from the `shakingSprites` array
    if (counter >= numberOfShakes) {
      sprite.x = startX;
      sprite.y = startY;
      shakingSprites.splice(shakingSprites.indexOf(sprite), 1);
    }
  }

  //The `angularShake` function
  //First set the initial tilt angle to the right (+1) 
  var tiltAngle = 1;

  function angularShake() {
    if (counter < numberOfShakes) {

      //Reset the sprite's rotation
      sprite.rotation = startAngle;

      //Reduce the magnitude
      magnitude -= magnitudeUnit;

      //Rotate the sprite left or right, depending on the direction,
      //by an amount in radians that matches the magnitude
      sprite.rotation = magnitude * tiltAngle;
      counter += 1;

      //Reverse the tilt angle so that the sprite is tilted
      //in the opposite direction for the next shake
      tiltAngle *= -1;
    }

    //When the shaking is finished, reset the sprite's angle and
    //remove it from the `shakingSprites` array
    if (counter >= numberOfShakes) {
      sprite.rotation = startAngle;
      shakingSprites.splice(shakingSprites.indexOf(sprite), 1);
      //console.log("removed")
    }
  }

}
```

However it only works for canvas sprites. How can I get it to work with HTML elements? Thanks.

Comment: why not use css animation ?

Comment: @zb' the shake function shown here is pretty sophisticated, it lets me set the angle, magnitude, and naturally lowers the amount of shaking as it ends.

Comment: @Harry My answer isn't your solution?

Comment: @Mohammad I'm looking for a flexible js solution.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I have adapted your function so that it works on DOM elements. It is a pretty hefty shake though, you might want to play with the parameters to damped it a little bit:

```
var shakingElements = [];

var shake = function (element, magnitude = 16, angular = false) {
  //First set the initial tilt angle to the right (+1) 
  var tiltAngle = 1;

  //A counter to count the number of shakes
  var counter = 1;

  //The total number of shakes (there will be 1 shake per frame)
  var numberOfShakes = 15;

  //Capture the element's position and angle so you can
  //restore them after the shaking has finished
  var startX = 0,
      startY = 0,
      startAngle = 0;

  // Divide the magnitude into 10 units so that you can 
  // reduce the amount of shake by 10 percent each frame
  var magnitudeUnit = magnitude / numberOfShakes;

  //The `randomInt` helper function
  var randomInt = (min, max) => {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  };

  //Add the element to the `shakingElements` array if it
  //isn't already there
  if(shakingElements.indexOf(element) === -1) {
    //console.log("added")
    shakingElements.push(element);

    //Add an `updateShake` method to the element.
    //The `updateShake` method will be called each frame
    //in the game loop. The shake effect type can be either
    //up and down (x/y shaking) or angular (rotational shaking).
    if(angular) {
      angularShake();
    } else {
      upAndDownShake();
    }
  }

  //The `upAndDownShake` function
  function upAndDownShake() {

    //Shake the element while the `counter` is less than 
    //the `numberOfShakes`
    if (counter < numberOfShakes) {

      //Reset the element's position at the start of each shake
      element.style.transform = 'translate(' + startX + 'px, ' + startY + 'px)';

      //Reduce the magnitude
      magnitude -= magnitudeUnit;

      //Randomly change the element's position
      var randomX = randomInt(-magnitude, magnitude);
      var randomY = randomInt(-magnitude, magnitude);

      element.style.transform = 'translate(' + randomX + 'px, ' + randomY + 'px)';

      //Add 1 to the counter
      counter += 1;

      requestAnimationFrame(upAndDownShake);
    }

    //When the shaking is finished, restore the element to its original 
    //position and remove it from the `shakingElements` array
    if (counter >= numberOfShakes) {
      element.style.transform = 'translate(' + startX + ', ' + startY + ')';
      shakingElements.splice(shakingElements.indexOf(element), 1);
    }
  }

  //The `angularShake` function
  function angularShake() {
    if (counter < numberOfShakes) {
      console.log(tiltAngle);
      //Reset the element's rotation
      element.style.transform = 'rotate(' + startAngle + 'deg)';

      //Reduce the magnitude
      magnitude -= magnitudeUnit;

      //Rotate the element left or right, depending on the direction,
      //by an amount in radians that matches the magnitude
      var angle = Number(magnitude * tiltAngle).toFixed(2);
      console.log(angle);
      element.style.transform = 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)';
      counter += 1;

      //Reverse the tilt angle so that the element is tilted
      //in the opposite direction for the next shake
      tiltAngle *= -1;

      requestAnimationFrame(angularShake);
    }

    //When the shaking is finished, reset the element's angle and
    //remove it from the `shakingElements` array
    if (counter >= numberOfShakes) {
      element.style.transform = 'rotate(' + startAngle + 'deg)';
      shakingElements.splice(shakingElements.indexOf(element), 1);
      //console.log("removed")
    }
  }

};
```

**DEMO**

Have a look at the demo in the fiddle. The `red` block is the regular `upAndDownShake`, whereas the `green` one uses `angularShake`:

https://jsfiddle.net/12aueufy/1/

Answer (score 29):

You can use css animation like this example

```css
@-webkit-keyframes shake {
    0% { -webkit-transform: translate(2px, 1px) rotate(0deg); } 
    10% { -webkit-transform: translate(-1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg); }
    20% { -webkit-transform: translate(-3px, 0px) rotate(1deg); }
    30% { -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 2px) rotate(0deg); }
    40% { -webkit-transform: translate(1px, -1px) rotate(1deg); }
    50% { -webkit-transform: translate(-1px, 2px) rotate(-1deg); }
    60% { -webkit-transform: translate(-3px, 1px) rotate(0deg); }
    70% { -webkit-transform: translate(2px, 1px) rotate(-1deg); }
    80% { -webkit-transform: translate(-1px, -1px) rotate(1deg); }
    90% { -webkit-transform: translate(2px, 2px) rotate(0deg); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: translate(1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg); }
}
.shake:hover {
    -webkit-animation-name: shake;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s;
    -webkit-transform-origin:50% 50%;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
.shake {
    display:inline-block
}
```

```html
<div class="shake">Shake me</div>
<img class="shake" src="https://www.w3.org/2008/site/images/logo-w3c-screen-lg" />
```

To change speed of shaking, change values of `animation-duration`, `translate()`, `rotate()`.

If you want to shake element using javascript see **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6r4k0son/)**

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you should take a look in Animate.css, https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/, this is a css library that provides a lot of animations, including a shake one... I hope that this might work for your problem!

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to have the animation done entirely with very simple CSS and JS.  The strategy involves two things:

- `transition: all 500ms;` — This bit of CSS means that anytime we want to do a transition (i.e., animation), that transition will complete in `500ms`.
- `transform(rotate)` — Then every CSS change takes place in 500ms, so, we can shake the icon with `margin-left` and `margin-right`, or, we can use `transform(rotate)`, let's try the latter!

Note: You can use any type of CSS effect here, try experimenting with something else!  I'm curious if there's anything better than `transform(rotate)`.

#### Demo

```js
const wiggletime = 100;

function rotateElement(el) {
  el.classList.add('rotateable');
  el.style.transform = 'rotate(20deg)';

  setTimeout(function() {
    el.style.transform = 'rotate(-20deg)';
    setTimeout(function() {
      el.style.transform = 'rotate(0deg)';
    }, wiggletime);
  }, wiggletime);

  return true;
}

function squishElement(el) {
  el.classList.add('rotateable');
  el.style.transform = 'scaleX(1.5)';

  setTimeout(function() {
    el.style.transform = 'scaleX(0.5)';
    setTimeout(function() {
      el.style.transform = 'scaleX(1)';
    }, wiggletime);
  }, wiggletime);

  return true;
}

function shakeElement(el) {
  el.classList.add('rotateable');
  el.style.marginLeft = '20px';

  setTimeout(function() {
    el.style.marginLeft = '-20px';
    setTimeout(function() {
      el.style.marginLeft = '0px';
    }, wiggletime);
  }, wiggletime);

  return true;
}

function skewElement(el) {
  el.classList.add('rotateable');
  el.style.transform = 'skewX(20deg)';

  setTimeout(function() {
    el.style.transform = 'skewX(-20deg)';
    setTimeout(function() {
      el.style.transform = 'skewX(0deg)';
    }, wiggletime);
  }, wiggletime);

  return true;
}

function borderElement(el) {
  el.classList.add('rotateable');
  el.style.border = '4px solid black';
  el.style.marginLeft = '-4px';
  el.style.marginTop = '-4px';

  setTimeout(function() {
    el.style.border = '2px solid black';
    el.style.marginLeft = '-2px';
    el.style.marginTop = '-2px';
    setTimeout(function() {
      el.style.border = '1px solid black';
      el.style.marginLeft = '0px';
      el.style.marginTop = '0px';
    }, wiggletime);
  }, wiggletime);

  return true;
}

document.getElementById('rotate-me').addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
  rotateElement(this);
});

document.getElementById('shake-me').addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
  shakeElement(this);
});

document.getElementById('squish-me').addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
  squishElement(this);
});

document.getElementById('skew-me').addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
  skewElement(this);
});

document.getElementById('border-me').addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
  borderElement(this);
});
```

```css
.rotateable {
    transition: all 100ms;
}
```

```html
<button id="shake-me">Shake Me!</button>

<br><br>

<button id="rotate-me">Rotate Me!</button>

<br><br>

<button id="squish-me">Squish Me!</button>

<br><br>

<button id="skew-me">Skew Me!</button>

<br><br>

<button id="border-me" style="position:absolute;">Border Me!</button>
```

#### Demo - Extended

Why not extended animations?

```js
const wiggletime = 100;

function rotateElement(el) {
  el.classList.add('rotateable');
  el.style.transform = 'rotate(20deg)';

  setTimeout(function() {
    el.style.transform = 'rotate(-20deg)';
    setTimeout(function() {
      el.style.transform = 'rotate(10deg)';
      setTimeout(function() {
        el.style.transform = 'rotate(-10deg)';
        setTimeout(function() {
          el.style.transform = 'rotate(0deg)';
        }, wiggletime);
      }, wiggletime);
    }, wiggletime);
  }, wiggletime);

  return true;
}

function squishElement(el) {
  el.classList.add('rotateable');
  el.style.transform = 'scaleX(1.5)';

  setTimeout(function() {
    el.style.transform = 'scaleX(0.5)';
    setTimeout(function() {
      el.style.transform = 'scaleX(1.25)';
      setTimeout(function() {
        el.style.transform = 'scaleX(0.75)';
        setTimeout(function() {
          el.style.transform = 'scaleX(1)';
        }, wiggletime);
      }, wiggletime);
    }, wiggletime);
  }, wiggletime);

  return true;
}

function skewElement(el) {
  el.classList.add('rotateable');
  el.style.transform = 'skewX(20deg)';

  setTimeout(function() {
    el.style.transform = 'skewX(-20deg)';
    setTimeout(function() {
      el.style.transform = 'skewX(10deg)';
      setTimeout(function() {
        el.style.transform = 'skewX(-10deg)';
        setTimeout(function() {
          el.style.transform = 'skewX(0deg)';
        }, wiggletime);
      }, wiggletime);
    }, wiggletime);
  }, wiggletime);

  return true;
}

function shakeElement(el) {
  el.classList.add('rotateable');
  el.style.marginLeft = '20px';

  setTimeout(function() {
    el.style.marginLeft = '-20px';
    setTimeout(function() {
      el.style.marginLeft = '10px';
      setTimeout(function() {
        el.style.marginLeft = '-10px';
        setTimeout(function() {
          el.style.marginLeft = '0px';
        }, wiggletime);
      }, wiggletime);
    }, wiggletime);
  }, wiggletime);

  return true;
}

document.getElementById('rotate-me').addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
  rotateElement(this);
});

document.getElementById('shake-me').addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
  shakeElement(this);
});

document.getElementById('squish-me').addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
  squishElement(this);
});

document.getElementById('skew-me').addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
  skewElement(this);
});
```

```css
.rotateable {
  transition: all 100ms;
}
```

```html
<button id="shake-me">Shake Me!</button>

<br><br>

<button id="rotate-me">Rotate Me!</button>

<br><br>

<button id="squish-me">Squish Me!</button>

<br><br>

<button id="skew-me">Skew Me!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function shake(e, oncomplete, distance, time) {
var time = 500;
var distance = 5;

var start = (new Date()).getTime();
animate();

function animate() {
    var now = (new Date()).getTime();
    // Get current time
    var elapsed = now - start;
    // How long since we started
    var fraction = elapsed / time;
    // What fraction of total time?
    if (fraction < 1) {
        var x = distance * Math.sin(fraction * 4 * Math.PI);
        e.style.left = x + "px";
        // We're aiming for a smooth 40 frames/second animation.
        setTimeout(animate, Math.min(25, time - elapsed));
    } else {
        // Otherwise, the animation is complete
        if (oncomplete) oncomplete(e);
        // Invoke completion callback
    }
   }
}

function shakeme(event1) {
    shake(event1.target);
}

document.getElementById("wood").addEventListener("mouseover", shakeme, false);
```

> HTML Element

```
<button id="wood">Hello World</button>
```

> Source

http://javascriipt.blogspot.com/2015/02/how-to-mimic-shake-animation-effect.html

Answer (score 0):

You could use some library for javascript animations like [Velocity](http://julian.com/research/velocity/)

It's really flexible and easy to use.

Please check this [working sample](https://jsbin.com/sujinas), I'm  pretty sure that you can create wished effect in minutes

Hope it help