# Shake animation with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ng-animate

I'm still learning AngularJS and have previously been using jQuery etc. to archive same feeling.

I have a login function which redirects a user if succesful login and otherwise - as for now - prints to the console.
I would like to "shake" the form-html-DOM if password is incorrect.

This is my code in my controller:

```
    user.login(self.username, self.password).then(
        function(res) {
            $location.path('/dashboard');
        }, function(res) {
            console.log(res.data.error);
        }
    );
```

With jQuery I would do something like:

```
    user.login(self.username, self.password).then(
        function(res) {
            $location.path('/dashboard');
        }, function(res) {
            $("#my-login-form").shake();
        }
    );
```

This is of course not good with AngularJS. What is the simplest and best way to do something similar? I've tried to read the ngAnimate docs, but need a better understanding/example of something like that.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36962903/javascript-shake-html-element/36964181#36964181

Comment: This is best done with CSS. Use Angular simply to attach a `class` on the login form, and define a CSS animation for that class to "shake" the form. I'd suggest to re-word the question and re-tag it as CSS question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to use ng-animate. [Here](https://css-tricks.com/animations-the-angular-way/) you can find a good tutorial to start using it. And [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/shake-css-keyframe-animation/) you can find a CSS3 animation to do the shake.

You will have to:

- Include angular-animate.js and ngAnimate to your angular module
- Assign CSS class with animation to form
- When login returns an error change the CSS class's animation property so it will play the animation.

You can find how to do points 1 and 3 in the first tutorial I sent to you and the css animation in the second one.

Comment: Seems to be working, but how do I remove the class after the shake animation, so it can shake once more if a user tries to login and fail twice?

Comment: I'm able to add $scope.shake = false just at the beginning of the function, but is that the best way?

Answer (score 5):

You could use CSS to add the animation. For instance [animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) and then use angular to add the class when something happens.

**Example:**

View:

```
<div ng-class="{'shake':error}" style="width:200px;height:200px;background:blue" class="animated"></div>
```

Controller:

```
user.login(self.username, self.password).then(
    function(res) {
        $location.path('/dashboard');
    }, function(res) {
        console.log(res.data.error);
        $scope.error = true;
        setTimeout(function(){ 
            $scope.error = false;
        }, 1000);
    }
);
```

**Explanation:**

> ng-class="{'shake':error}"

conditionally add the "shake" class if the error variable is true. Together with the "animated" the shake effect is triggered as defined in animated.css. You could of course create your own css styles as well.

**Demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/mkraLxs3/3/

Comment: It seems I can only shake the form once, as the class is being added and then exists all the time. How can I shake the div in your example every time I click the button?

Comment: @Michael Nielsen Use a timeout and set $scope.error = false in it.

Comment: @dz210 Can you add it to your jsfiddle, please?

Comment: @MatijaŽupančić I added the timeout to my answer. You can of course use Angular's $timeout too